# Telerik-RadRadioButtonlist control is not loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik, radiobuttonlist

```
<telerik:RadPanelBar runat="server" Visible="true" Border="false" ID="pnlMain" Width="600px">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadPanelItem runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="tfName" Label="Partner / Client Group Name:"
                    Display="true" LabelWidth="180px" Width="600px" />
                <telerik:RadLabel runat="server" ID="RadioLabel" Text="Partner / Client Group:"                Visible="true" />
                <telerik:RadRadioButtonList ID="rgPcg" runat="server" Direction="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <telerik:ButtonListItem runat="server" Text="Partner" Selected="true" Value="Partner"/>
                        <telerik:ButtonListItem runat="server" Text="Client Group" Value="Client Group"/>
                  </Items>
               </telerik:RadRadioButtonList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadPanelItem>
   </Items>
</telerik:RadPanelBar>
```

`Why my control RadRadioButtonList 'rgPcg' is not loading while we run the application and other two controls(tfName,RadioLabel) are displaying fine.
it's not showing in designer.cs page as well.

I have placed same control in other screens and those are working fine. but in this screen it is not working.

Please help me in this.
`

Comment: Control works fine adding it as markup to a page, so the issue is not in the control itself but is in the page you are putting it on. We will need the markup for the page that you are putting the control into. Is this in a user control? Are you using ajax on this control? Are you receiving a console error in the page you are placing it on?

Comment: I'm using this control under ajax control. why is it not allowing me to use the control under ajax control? radiobuttongroup is not working because of this ajax control only.

Comment: No idea. You'll need to add an example to your OP of where it is not working. Please include the markup for the page at minimum. The code behind may also be necessary.